# AngularJS orderBy on select boxes doesn't work as expected.

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am trying to convert an old PHP/JS project over to straight AngularJS.

The issue I'm running into is that the `orderBy:"name"` on my select box is only sort of working.

For example, in the plunker (below) if you open the building drop down, it appears to be in the correct alphabetical order. However, there's a few that are just randomly misplaced throughout the drop down.

The other odd thing is that the JSON file is already in alphabetical order, so I'm not sure what the deal is.

I am new to AngularJS, so I know I'm missing something that's small. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wHSERdfKLaYaaSMBph73

JSON Example:

```
{
    "id": 110,
    "name": "Administration Center",
    "address": null,
    "latitude": "41.256326",
    "longitude": "-95.973784",
    "content": "",
    "overlay": "g|xzFnywhQ?^^??j@M??^r@??_@K??kA",
    "url": "",
    "type_id": 3,
    "show_marker": 0,
    "show_label": 1,
    "custom_marker": "",
    "created_at": "2013-07-10 15:40:09",
    "updated_at": "2013-07-10 15:42:50",
    "color": "#08c"
}
```

Comment: Good post for your first try. I'm sure this will be answered quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Your plunker had some errors in the order of your dependancies (ie: jquery after angular, etc. There is an error message in the dev console). When using angular and jquery, you have to include jquery first.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/underscorejs/1.5.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Here is your demo with the fixes: http://plnkr.co/edit/92zvkjP1cx1wBlGqwB4D?p=preview

You do not need to order your data in the controller if you are using the `orderBy` filter.

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,menu) in menus">
    <h1>{{typeIds[key]}}</h1>
    <select ng-model="selectedlocation" 
            ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in menu | orderBy:'name'">
    </select>
</div>
```

**js**

```
function menuController($scope, $http) {
    // probably not the best way to do this
    $scope.typeIds = {3: "Buildings", 6: "Parking (Fac/Staff)", 7: "Parking (Public)", 8: "Parking (Student)", 11: "Landmarks"};

    $http.get('locations.json').then(function(res) {
        $scope.locations = res.data;
        $scope.menus = _($scope.locations).groupBy('type_id');

        /*
        // This is not needed anymore
        //Convert to array so it sorts correctly on the view side. 
        $scope.orderedMenus = [];
        _($scope.menus).each(function(data, key) {
            $scope.orderedMenus.push({"key" : key, "data" : data})
        });
        */
    });
}
```

Comment: "you have to include jquery first" -- angular has a small version of jquery embeedded, so why have jquery at all?

Comment: I don't know how he uses jquery in his own project, but he tried to include it, so that's why I said that. Whenever you do, jquery must come before angular, so angular can use it. Jquery has neat functions that can be useful in larger projects prehaps.

Comment: Hey jpmorin. This is awesome. Thanks so much for your help. I was going to go insane. The only reason jquery is in there is for the bootstrap dependency even though I wasn't even really using it.

Comment: By default, you would not ne able to use thé JavaScript from bootstrap components with angular. What people do is they incluse only thé bootstrap css ans thé angular-ui directives for bootsrap rewritten for angular. Look for it on Google! It may still require jquery.

Comment: Sorry about the typos, I was on mobile. By default, you would not be able to use the JavaScript from bootstrap components with angular. What people do is they include only the bootstrap css and use angular-ui (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which contains directives written in angular to replace bootsrap components. It may still require jquery.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/yRR34nwCBIh6cAiTXIBP?p=preview

It looks to me like `ng-select` just doesn't like to order on anything but the value (edit: it looks like that's not right exactly). So I did a bit of sorting in the controller with underscore and made a more explicit select:

```
 <div ng-repeat="menu in orderedMenus | orderBy:'name'"><!-- orderBy might not be necessary here --> 
  <h1>{{typeIds[menu.key]}}</h1>
  <select ng-model="selectedlocation">
   <option ng-repeat="item in  menu" value="item.id">
    {{item.name}}
   </option>
  </select>     
 </div>
```

Which does the trick. [Screenshot here](http://imgur.com/HHe2U5u).

Comment: Frankly jpmorin has the better answer here -- he actually fixed the problem, I worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a better solution posted here now.  But, just so you know your options in these situations, you can write you own sort as `orderBy` can take a sort function, for example:

```
  <select ng-model="selectedlocation" ng-options="value.id as value.name for (key,value) in menu.data | orderBy:sortFunction"></select>
```

If you add something like the following in your controller:

```
$scope.sortFunction = function(item){
   console.log("Parameter: ", item.name);
}
```

You'll see you get the item name.  If you go this route, your job is to return a value from `sortFunction()` that when evaluated against the <, =, > operator produces whatever sort you'd like.

I'm not recommending this route- just mentioning it for completeness sake.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy